# Protocol Buffers to Json Conversion

Tags: java, spring-boot, type-conversion, apache-camel

I am working on ProtoBuf to Json Conversion using Apache Camel Spring Boot. Here, I receive file from input directory in Processor and have to convert to JSON and send to the endpoint.

I know by using JsonFormat I can accomplish but how do I create MessageOrBuilder?
Since I am getting it in String format" and it accepts MessageOrBuilder and passing "body" gives me error. Please help.

My code:

`String json = JsonFormat.printer().print(MessageOrBuilder);`

My Processor:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Entered ProtoBufToJson processor");
        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        logger.info("Obtained proto body: " + body);
        String json = JsonFormat.printer().print(body);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(json.toString());
}
```

Comment: if you get an error, share the error message

Comment: Hi Jens, this is what I had given since I have no idea how to do: String json = JsonFormat.printer().print(body); ERROR: Change type of body to "MessageOrBuilder"

Comment: Well where are you actually getting the protocol buffer object that is being converted?

Comment: Hi, if you see String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class); - in this I am getting the protobuf object.